# Php remove spaces, commas and insert to database

Tags: php, mysql

I put data from exel into database (Mysql price decimal(9,2).

How to remove spaces, commas (replace with dot ".") before inserting to database?

After inserting data (price) to the database I have 1.00 and I should have 1235.00

**Exel file -> price**

```
1 456,34
1 350,21
1 200,00
1 235,23
300,14
350,00
345,00
436,00
436,00
```

php file

```
foreach($data as $row)
        {

        $price = str_replace(' ', '', ':price');
        $price = str_replace(',', '.', $price);
        $price = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $price);

            $insert_data = array(
                ':sym_id'       =>  $row[0],
                ':code'         =>  $row[1],
                ':name'         =>  $row[2],
                ':quantity'     =>  $row[3],
                ':price'        =>  $row[4],
                ':position'     =>  $row[5],
                ':visible'      =>  $row[6]
            );

            $query = "
            INSERT INTO symphony 
            (sym_id, code, name, quantity, price, position, visible) 
            VALUES (:sym_id, :code, :name, :quantity, $price, :position, :visible)
            ";

            $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
            $statement->execute($insert_data);
        }
```

Comment: @Qirel it is about "decimal"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I don't know what you're expecting:

```
$price = str_replace(' ', '', ':price');
$price = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $price);
```

to do. But what ends up happening is you have a variable called `$price`, filled with the value `':price'`. I suspect this evaluates to `true`, causing MySQL to place 1.00 into the decimal field.

I think you're trying to end up with a comma substituted with a decimal point in price. This would be closer:

```
foreach($data as $row)
        {
            //Remove the price conversion. It did nothing

            $insert_data = array(
                ':sym_id'       =>  $row[0],
                ':code'         =>  $row[1],
                ':name'         =>  $row[2],
                ':quantity'     =>  $row[3],
                ':price'        =>  preg_replace('/,/', '.', $row[4]), //Replace you're comma with a point
                ':position'     =>  $row[5],
                ':visible'      =>  $row[6]
            );

            //Use only named values here. Don't put the variable '$price' in here at all
            $query = "
            INSERT INTO symphony 
            (sym_id, code, name, quantity, price, position, visible) 
            VALUES (:sym_id, :code, :name, :quantity, :price, :position, :visible)
            ";

            $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
            //Use insert data to fill the named parameters
            $statement->execute($insert_data);
        }
```

But wait... What happens if the user is also using the `.` as a thousands separator and the `,` as a decimal separator. Then you need to go a step further, and use PHP's number formatter. Details are here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parse.php

EDIT:

I see you've changed the lines in the loop slightly since I started writing the answer:

```
$price = str_replace(' ', '', ':price');
$price = str_replace(',', '.', $price);
$price = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $price);
```

The effect is still the same however: At the end of these lines `$price` === `':price'`. The third parameter to `str_replace` is the string these lines change, and it contains neither a comma nor a space.

Comment: Nightmare space is a comma in Exel. Thank you for your help. `preg_replace('/,/', '', $row[4]),`